# pyspark fill values with join instead of isin

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to fill [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark) dataframe on rows where several column values are found in other dataframe columns but I cannot use `.collect().distinct()` and `.isin()` since it takes a long time compared to join.
How can I use join or broadcast when filling values conditionally?
In [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) I would do:

```
df.loc[(df.A.isin(df2.A)) | (df.B.isin(df2B)), 'new_column'] = 'new_value'
```

UPD: so far I tried this approach in pyspark but it did not work right judging by `.count()` before and after (rows count is artificially decreased)

```
count_first = df.count()
dfA_1 = df.join(df2, 'A', 'leftanti') \
  .withColumn('new_column', F.lit(None).cast(StringType()))
dfA_2= df.join(df2, 'A', 'inner') \
  .withColumn('new_column', F.lit('new_value'))
df = dfA_1 .unionByName(dfA_2)
count_second = df.count()
cont_first - count_second
```

How can I achieve the same in [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark) but with join ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check below example, i think that you can do something similar

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = [
    {"A": "1", "B": "1"},
    {"A": "2", "B": "2"},
]

df2 = [
    {"A": "1"},
    {"A": "22"},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2).withColumn("C", F.lit("dummy"))

count_first = df.count()
df.join(df2, "A", "left").withColumn(
    "newValue", F.when(F.col("C").isNull(), F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.lit("new_value"))
).drop("C").show()
```

The output is

```
+---+---+---------+
|  A|  B| newValue|
+---+---+---------+
|  1|  1|new_value|
|  2|  2|     null|
+---+---+---------+
```

Comment: Hey, thanks this would have worked but I only have single column in that second dataframe since it's my attempt to have alternative to `.isin()`. Could you suggest what would've you done in such case (with no other column C to look for as merge indicator?)

Comment: In such case you need to try approach from your example (two joins to filter out and then union). But i think that you can just add some fake column and then drop it, please check updated answer